# Empty message body with graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I try to get the message body using graphapi I can't get it even if I extract the id and the number of unread messages I was thinking about permission, but I add the read_inbox permission and when trying the tools of developer the message was saying field is empty or disallowed by the access token, and I have this message saying

```
error": {
   "message": "You can only access the \"inbox\" connection for the current user.", 
   "type": "GraphMethodException", 
   "code": 100
```

Comment: How about posting the code that's giving you this error message?

Answer (score 1):

As the error message indicates, you probably tried to access the inbox content of a friend.

```
graph.facebook.com/USER_ID?fields=inbox
```

For evident privacy reasons, this is impossible. You can only consult **your own** inbox:

```
graph.facebook.com/me?fields=inbox
```

Comment: I see hootsuite can do that. they can read my inbox. How did they do that?

Comment: This is what I just said.

Answer (score 0):

My application reads posts, home, inbox, insights and other data of any user who has logged into my application and have given permission to my application to do these things on his/her behalf. I have found following solution and it worked for reading inbox.

```
graph.facebook.com/USER_ID?fields=threads
```

The inbox edge has been deprecated and now threads can be used instead. You need `read_page_mailboxes` for pages and `read_mailbox` for account to read inbox messages.